How to import sketchup file in Blender clean way
Importing with skp addon getting error and the file is unable to import. I tried with collada and obj file format but all the file getting mess.

ORIGINAL FILE IN SKETCHP

How to import the file clean as seen in the sketchup. Whats the issue and how to solve it. Any suggestion or help. Thanks
Download sketchup file here (sketchup file)

FWIW. A few more details might help someone to help you. What version of Blender? What version of Sketchup? What OS? What importer addon? Are the versions of Blender and Sketchup each compatible with the addon? Have you tried splitting your object into smaller parts and exporting them as collada or obj files?

Sketchup version 2022 but i have save in lower version also 2013, blender i tried in 3.5 & 4.0, i tried with smaller part some work some does not, i tried with dae and obj file but not satisfied with the file imported.

You didn't mention what importer you are using. You might try this one, if you haven't. It says that it supports Blender 3.2 and Sketchup 2022: https://github.com/RedHaloStudio/Sketchup_Importer/releases/tag/0.23.0
